# Access the values stored in an array created by .map()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary

Writing a resume creator in, in a previous question I was using a for loop to dynamically generate an array from form inputs. Based on another users advice I instead used the .map() method to store the values.

```
var jobtitle = $('input[id^=jobtitle]').map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

Unfortunately I can't figure out how to access the stored values outside of this function!

```
$('#resumejobs').append('<div id ="resumejob' + jobs + ' "><div id = "jt' + i + ' " ' +   'class = "jobtitle">' + jobtitle[0] +'<br /></div><div class = "joblocation"</div></div>');
```

I thought that .map() stored the values in a new array named jobtitle, it seems I was wrong because when I run my program, the title of the first job is not displayed in the jobtitle div.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r2EX6/9/

Is there a way to access the data stored in the .map() outside of the function that created it? Or is there some kind of workaround?

Comment: `var` declares a local variable, which you cannot use outside the function unless you `return` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently declaring all of your `.map()` variables inside this function:

```
$('#experiencesave').click(function () {
```

Declare the variables outside this function, then access them and assign them inside here as you normally would. Ex:

```
var jobtitles;
$('#experiencesave').click(function () {
    jobtitles = .....
});
```